# How to speed up a selection of a subset of data in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

I have a huge Table with lots of data in it (170GB Compressed size, 3.8 Million Rows) and wanna select a subset of this data.

This subset is defined by a list of uris. The column with the uris in my table has an hash index on it.

So the simple query would be

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE uri IN ("uri1","uri2","uri")
```

But this query is incredibly slow. For something about 190 uris it lasts over 6 hours

```
Query OK, 240777 rows affected (6 hours 46 min 1.34 sec)
```

Is there a way to speed up this selection? At the moment it is faster to iterate over the whole database in an external tool and dumping out the relevant rows.

**EDIT**

Here is the EXPLAIN of my query:

```
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | SOURCES | range | site_uri      | site_uri | 257     | NULL | 421418 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Also interested in the answer to this question.

Comment: please post the query and the EXPLAIN of your query

Comment: You can test to put the search URIs in an tmp table with one field and index and then select j.* from tmptable t LEFT JOIN bigtable j ON t.uri = j.uri

Comment: Does this kind of query run fast?
`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE uri = "uri1"`

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: `rows affected` ??  That comes after a write query, not after a `SELECT`.

Comment: 240K rows had those 190 uris?  That's why it took hours.  What did you do with the 10GB of output?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on uri column?

The index alone may help. If not, then UNION could make things faster (although quite ugly):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE uri = "uri1"
UNION 
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE uri = "uri2"
UNION
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE uri = "uri"
```

Comment: Yes, there is an index on the uri column